# Wake-on-lan from suspend

Tags: networking, xubuntu, suspend

I am trying to wake up my laptop from suspend using WOL but it didn't work at all.

I found this old post for the same problem but I don't see how I can do this for Xubuntu 14.04 that I am using. I don't see the same files on the same path this post described.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642272

Does anyone know what/how I can solve this?

Note: I can power on this laptop using WOL. This means this laptop and its network card supports WOL, the problem is obviously somewhere in Xubuntu. I can see this laptop's network card leds are both on when it is in suspend mode.

I have the same problem on another Ubuntu 14.04 installation on a Desktop computer which can also be turned on using WOL.